# ObjectOutputStream throwing Exception

Tags: java, android, serversocket, objectoutputstream

I'm trying to write a simple client/server program, where the client is an android app and the server is a Raspberry Pi 4. All I want to do is allow the client to type a message and have the Raspberry Pi display the message on the terminal. However, my app keeps throwing an exception at the `out.writeObject(message_text)` line in the `sendMessage()` method.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText message;
    private Button send;
    private ObjectOutputStream out;
    private Socket socket;
    private String raspi_ip = "enter ip here";
    private int raspi_portnum = 12345;
    Client client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        message = findViewById(R.id.message_text);
        send = findViewById(R.id.send_button);

        try{
            client = new Client(raspi_ip,raspi_portnum);
            client.start();

        } catch (Exception e){
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setTitle("Error! ").setMessage("Couldn't connect to server.").setNeutralButton("OK", null).create().show();
        }

        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                client.sendMessage();
            }
        });
    }

    private void closeConnection(){
        try{
            out.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        closeConnection();
    }

    private class Client extends Thread {
        private String ip_address;
        private int port_number;

        public Client(String ipaddress,int portnum){
            this.ip_address = ipaddress;
            this.port_number = portnum;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            connectToServer(ip_address,port_number);
        }

        public void connectToServer(String ipaddress, int portnum){
            try{
                socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(ipaddress),portnum);
                out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                out.flush();
            }catch (Exception e){
                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.setTitle("Error! ").setMessage("Couldn't connect to server.").setNeutralButton("OK", null).create().show();
            }
        }

        public void sendMessage(){
            String message_text = message.getText().toString();
            try{
                out.writeObject(message_text);
                out.flush();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.setTitle("Error! ").setMessage("IO Exception.").setNeutralButton("OK", null).create().show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the server side java program:

```
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class RaspPiServer {
    
    private ServerSocket server;

    public RaspPiServer(){
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        RaspPiServer server = new RaspPiServer();
        server.runServer();
    }

    public void runServer(){
        try{
            server = new ServerSocket(12345,100);
            while (true){
                new Controller(server.accept()).start();
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class Controller extends Thread {

        private Socket socket;
        private ObjectInputStream input;
        private String in;

        public Controller(Socket socket){
            this.socket = socket;
            System.out.println("New client at " + socket.getRemoteSocketAddress());
        }

        @Override
        public void run(){
            try{
                input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                while (!(in = (String)input.readObject()).equals("close")){
                    System.out.println(in);
                }
            } catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                closeConnection();
                System.out.println("Connection with client @ " + socket.getRemoteSocketAddress() + " closed");
            }
        }

        private void closeConnection() {
            try {
                input.close();
                socket.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Is there an easy fix here, or am I missing something bigger?

Comment: `All I want to do is allow the client to type a message and have the Raspberry Pi display the message on the terminal. ` Ok. but then do not use writeObject to write simple strings. You can just use write().

Comment: Also do not use ObjectInputStream as the raspiu will not send objects but just a simple text line i suppose. Use .readLine() to read the lines.

Comment: But.... You did not tell which exception you have. Pretty bad!!!! You have a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Look in the logcat.